# Simple Struct definition in C for Red Black Tree

Tags: c, struct, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I don't use the C language since years and now I need it again.
I'm trying to build a Red-Black Tree but I'm stuck at the beginning because I'm missing something about "structs".

Take a look to my "structs" declarations please, they are easy.
This is a header file included in Red_black_tree.c

```
 #define BLACK 0 //defalut color
#define RED 1 //

struct Node {  //create a black node by default, to have a red one look at "create_red_node"
    struct Node *left = NULL;
    struct Node *right= NULL;
    int key = 0;
    int value = 0;
    char color = BLACK;
};

struct Root_t {
    struct Node* Root;
};

struct Node* create_node () {
    struct Node* black = (Node*) malloc (sizeof(Node));
    return black;
}

struct Node* create_red_node () {
    struct Node* red = create_node ();
    red->color=RED;
    return red;
}

Root_t* create_tree () {
    struct Root_t* fake=(Root_t*) malloc (sizeof(Root_t));
    struct fake->Root->left=create_red_node ();
    struct fake->Root->right=create_red_node ();
    return fake;
}
```

I compiled with "gcc Red_black_tree.c  -o RBTree".
GCC says something like : "expected ';' at end of declaration list" 7 times, or "must use 'struct' tag to refer to type... ", "expected identifier...".
What do you think, is it good to create RBTree?

Comment: `struct Node *left = NULL;` that's not valid C code for a declaration of a `struct` member.  Wash, rinse, repeat for all of the similar occurrences in this code. And your closing question has little to do with that error; It's fine to implement an RB tree in any language you like, so long as you're proficient in the language in the first place.

Comment: Suggest that you set the default values in the function `create_node`

Answer (score 2):

In C, you can not assign while you define the members of a `struct`

Instead of

```
struct T {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
};
```

you need something like

```
struct T {
    int a;
    int b;
};
...
struct T t = {.a = 1, .b = 2};
```

In addition, all your members are set to 0 (`NULL` is an alias of `(void *)0`), when you want to allocate memory and initialize all to zero at the same time you can use `calloc`

```
struct Node* black = calloc(1, sizeof(*black)); // Dont cast malloc and friends
```

And here:

```
struct fake->Root->left=create_red_node();
```

, you don't want the `struct` keyword, instead:

```
fake->Root->left=create_red_node();
```

Another suggestion: do not hardcode the data of the red-black-tree in the structure, (`int key, value;`) even if it works you end up with a non reusable container, instead, use a generic pointer to `void` (`void *data;`) and a callback to your comparison functions in the implementation.

```
struct Node *insert(struct Node *root, int (*comparer)(const void *, const void *)) ...
```

Comment: Thank you David, I posted a comment to say "Thank you" to you and everyone but seems like I didn't have to write it...About the last part, you're saying that I should use "void" because it doesn't force me to keep the "int" but I can use what I want like " char, long int...." right? Like struct { void key, void value....}...

Comment: You are welcome. And yes, of course you can embed in the struct whatever you want.